# Is there a built in way to add a gesture recognizer (specifically pan) just to the right or left edges of a view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

Throughout iOS 7 there's many situations where users can slide their finger in from the left or right edge of the screen in order to perform an action, such as popping a view controller or showing a sidebar.

Is there a built in way to do this that I've completely overlooked somehow (yes, I've searched extensively)? Or is the only way to check the frame position of where the pan started?

This is because I want to perform distinct actions if the user pulls from the edge, or say the middle.

Answer (score 3):

You have [`UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer/edges), which is added to iOS7 to detect, well, panning from the edges of the screen. For panning from the middle, a normal pan gesture recognizer will suffice, where you can check if the pan gesture originated close enough to the middle.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer`, but check that it's available first (since it's iOS 7+):

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer")) {
    UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer =
    [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                      action:@selector(handleScreenEdgePanGesture:)];
    panRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdgeLeft;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Set up gestures**

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanning:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

**Handling gesture states**

```
- (void)handlePanning:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    switch ([gestureRecognizer state])
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:

            [self startDragging:gestureRecognizer];
            break;

         //u won't need following cases
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:

            [self stopDragging:gestureRecognizer];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Recognizing start point of drag**

```
- (void)startDragging:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint pointInSrc = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:yourVIEW];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pan gesture recognizer is a predefined recognizer, about all you can do with it is to determine how fast the user moved their finger. If you want to tell if where the movement started, you'll have to code your own recognizer. It's not that difficult, you'll be notified when the touch started and where it ended.